# "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" postgresql error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

How it say: problem one by one doesn't walk.
I trying to realize request:

```
UPDATE payment
  SET 
      payment_amount =
(
    SELECT(r.rental_time * ca.price_per_day) AS payment_amount
    FROM car ca
        JOIN rental r ON ca.car_id = r.car_id
        JOIN payment pay ON pay.rental_id = r.rental_id
    WHERE ca.car_id
);
```

But I get error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I need that payment amount calculated depend on rental_time and car_id, example:

| car_id | price_per_day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25.43 |
| 2 | 56.12 |
| 3 | 23.9 |

| rental_id | rental_time(days) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 15 |

Comment: It seems youre missing a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement. With the current approach, you would set the same value of `payment_amount` for all rows in the `payment` table. Apart from that, the error message indicates that you're returning several rows in your in your subquery, making your command invalid (i.e. there should be only one value returning from it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original fails because the `WHERE` clause is broken and the subquery produces many rows. A correlated subquery is typically not the best approach to begin with.

Assuming there is no one-to-many relationship in the wrong direction, this would work:

```sql
UPDATE payment AS p
SET    payment_amount = r.rental_time * c.price_per_day
FROM   car    c
JOIN   rental r USING (car_id)
WHERE  p.rental_id = r.rental_id;
```

Subtle difference: this does *nothing* if no matching row is found in `car` and / or `rental` - while a correlated subquery would set `payment_amount` to NULL in this case. (Plus, it's faster for many rows.)

[The manual about `UPDATE`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)